# ImportError: cannot import name 'auto' from 'tqdm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tqdm

My Python version is 3.7.0 version

To import tensorflow_datasets,

```
import tensorflow_datasets
```

I ran the code, but:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'auto' from 'tqdm'
```

So, how can I import the auto? When I searched the `auto` library:

```
ERROR : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement auto
ERROR : No matching distribution found for auto
```

I trying to look for `auto` library at anaconda environment. But I can't find the same name 'auto' exactly. Which library does 'auto' belong to?

Comment: does. this help? https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/899

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, it's from `tqdm`, which I've only ever used for progress bars. In the [tqdm GitHub](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm), they import something from `tqdm.auto`. Also, running `from tqdm import auto` works for me, so I'm guessing it's from there.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I will search for tqdm link!